# Camel with old version of SonicMQ (5.02)

Tags: jms, apache-camel

Wondering is it possible to integrate Camel with a very old version of Sonic MQ (5.02). The queues in one of the legacy application we have, were built in 2003! When we try to post using Camel (with the sonic client jar on the classpath) we get class not found exceptions from Camel...

java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.createConnection()Ljavax/jms/Connection;

This relates to the old version of JMS api (1.02b) shipped with Sonic.
Even if we put the correct version of JMS API on class path.. we get further... but then various sonic exceptions .....

Wondering if it is even supported?? Has anyone tried this..
or have info the could share?

Much Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Camel do you use?

Camel does not support JMS 1.0 api for a very long time. You would need to use an old version of Camel. In fact that happend form Camel 2.5 onwards, see its release notes: http://camel.apache.org/camel-250-release.html

Comment: Using Camel 2.14.0.  The version of Sonic we are using is so old, that I cant find documentation on it, so not actually sure which version of JMS it implements. The javax.jms class files inside the JMS api jar shipped inside the sonic_cleint jar have timestamp of 2003... which could indicate JMS 1.1.

Comment: I have since found some documentation on SonicMQ 5.02, and it is JMS version 1.02b... arrgh upto 2001. I was hoping to use (the superb) Camel to do a Reply/Response... Any ideas? May have to implement Reply/Response ourselves with JMS 1.02b API...